# Upgrading to Fedora 29 from 28 resulted into inaccessible SSH and other TLS dependent services

Tags: fedora, upgrade

**After running standard distro upgrade command for Fedora Server:**

`dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=29 && dnf system-upgrade reboot`

and rebooting back to the server I could not connect to any service that is running using TLS/SSL - no DNF, SSH, Apache (using https), Dovecot and other.

**Various errors appeared in logs:**

```
routines:ssl_cipher_list to_bytes no ciphers available
bio routines bio connect error crypto sock 2
no peer certificate available
```

**What could be the cause and possible solution for it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging deeper for some time, I have figured out that `crypto-policies` where not setup correctly to be symlinked to `DEFAULT` but to `FUTURE` instead.

**Solution was straight forward.**

Remove current package containing *crypto-policies* by running:

```
rpm -e --nodeps crypto-policies
```

Clearing left-overs under policies directory:

```
rm -rf /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/*
```

Finally reinstalling the package. Package manager (DNF) doesn't work as set to use secure connection.

First find and download the package (in the future version number will change and the link become broken, then simply open the location and search for the package name manually):

```
wget http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/fedora/linux/releases/29/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/c/crypto-policies-20180925-1.git71ca85f.fc29.noarch.rpm
```

Then install it:

```
rpm -i crypto-policies-20180925-1.git71ca85f.fc29.noarch.rpm
```

---

That is it. You can now use TLS/SSL over again.